# How can we create IBInspectable like checkmark?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I created lots of IBInspectable. But today, I observed that Xcode having some properties like this:

[image]

In the link, I marked rectangle box. I want to create custom IBInspectable like that. I don't know that is possible or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't have a checkbox. Creating a bool `@IBInspectable` will give you an on/off drop-down control in the inspector.

Comment: on/off drop means Its Bool @IBInspectable that I know. But I just want to know checkbox is possible or not.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: @SanjaysinhChauhan Please check my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to create Custom IBDesignable

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

step 3: add this code in created customTextView file

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class customTextView: UITextView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
    didSet{
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet{
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0 {
    didSet{
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet{
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffSet: CGSize = CGSize.zero {
    didSet{
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffSet
    }
}

}
```

Step 4:

[image]

Step 5: Here you get you custom fields

[image]

Comment: @Sanjaysinh Chauhan if you get your answer then please accept answer and upvote thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to create IBInspectable. 
But I want to create an IBInspectable show in the above question link. In the link, a 2nd rounded box has checkmark IBInspectable. I want to create like that. I don't know that is possible or not. So, Please answer if you have any alternate way.